# Get Multiple Order details Magento 1

Tags: sales-order, magento-1.14

I am using Magento ver. 1.14.2.4

I am trying to get order detail's for 6-7 orders, want to log their data into (var/log)

What's the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to get multiple order collection :

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array(6,7)));
Mage::log(print_r($orders->getData()),null,'Rohan.log',true);
```

Comment: Does it include shipping address data ? or need to use $orders->getShippingAddress->getData(); ?

Comment: inside foreach of $orders, you will get shipping address data.

Comment: can't we use direct method ?

Comment: Then, you need to load specific order by specific id. If you want to get collection of order by multiple order ids then, you need to run foreach for that.

Comment: ok, i will check. Thankyou

Comment: For order load by specific id : $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(6); print_r($order->getShippingAddress->getData());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116642/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-hamendra-sunthwal).